# How can I fix certain UWP applications and system features following a recent Windows update?

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting

I've recently started experiencing problems with my Windows 10 PC. As far as I can tell it seems to be that most UWP (Windows Store style) apps, and a number of built-in system features, won't run. For example:

- The Start Menu is not displayed, e.g. when I click the icon or use a keyboard shortcut.
- The new System Settings interface does not open when running `ms-settings:` from the Run dialog.
- Various programs (e.g. calculator and Word) do not run when opened using Explorer.
- The right-hand notification panel will not open when clicking the system tray icon.

On the other hand, several other programs appear to run without issues, for example: Firefox, Windows Explorer, Control Panel and Windows Defender.

---

This seems to be happening since I recently applied a Windows update (in May 2016).

I also updated Office 365 from the 2013 to 2016 version, and installed Eclipse, at the same time - but these seem less likely to have caused the problem.

---

A number of diagnostic utilities seem to recognise that there is a problem, but are unable to fix it:

- Running `sfc /scannow` results in the following message: `Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log...`
- Running the Start menu troubleshooter from [this support page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/get-help-windows-start-menu) finds this issue: `"Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost" and "Microsoft.Windows.Cortana" applications need to be installed correctly.`

---

Aside from the above, there are several solutions suggested by various questions here, Windows support discussions, elsewhere on the web, and my previous experience:

- Applying further Windows updates. Unfortunately not possible as this requires the Settings app to be working. Command line methods of installing updates do not seem to work either.
- Reboot. Done several times, without improvement.
- Create a new account on the PC. Aside from the inconvenience of transferring everything to a new account, as far as I can tell it's not possible to create an account through Control Panel so without Settings working this is not possible.
- Windows Firewall. This is enabled as appropriate.
- Reset the PC. I'd rather find a less drastic solution.
- This Powershell script (`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`) appears to run but without producing an improvement.
- System Restore. The available restore point is not restoreable in my case.
- DISM. This does not find any issues.
- Safe Mode. This produces a slight improvement in that the Settings app displays the initial menu page, however attempting to do anything results in a crash. All other behaviour appears to be the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: Unfortunately due to SO low rep restrictions I can't currently post links to all articles and questions that I've checked

Comment: try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3152599

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it seems to be a different issue as the update didn't fix things